# Is there a way to automate back-up on SQL Express LocalDB?

Tags: sql-server, spatial, sql-server-express

I am new to the gis world, and my boss wants me to find a way to automate the process to create back-ups on a local SQL Express DB. I know that I can create one for nonlocal DBs, however, I was wondering if there was a way to also automate at the local level.

I haven't been able to find any information on how to create this at all, most posts say it's not for local DBs.Is this true?

Comment: Perhaps better asked on sister site, DBA.StackExchange.com

Comment: You can create a batch script to backup, then set up schedule in Task Scheduler.

Comment: Consider using a proper tool for this, such as SQL Backup Master.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use a command line to do the backup, you can use programming to automate that. Case closed.